# How to check from adb the current screen in emulator is an AlertDialog or Activity?

Tags: android, android-emulator, uiautomatorviewer

I am trying to automate the analysis of Android applications. Is there any way to check from the shell that the displayed screen in the emulator is an Activity or AlertDialog?

I tried UiAutomator for dumping the screen in the emulator. XML dump file generated for Activity and DialogAlert seems similar (could not find new fields or any interesting differences to distinguish an Activity screen and an AlertDialog screen)

Using the `adb shell dumpsys activity activities | grep mFocusedActivity` command I can access the current Activity name. When tried this command from the AlertDialog screen, it dumped the same name as that of the Activity containing the AlertDialog. So is there any command to get the current DialogAlert name?

Comment: can you elaborate more?

Comment: @kdblue I have elaborated the problem with scenario and tryouts